# The most efficient way to find the point where maximum number of intervals overlap with python

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals

Consider I have a log register for users' entry and exit times from some server. I need to find the time at which there are maximum sessions. If there are more than one possible answer, the smallest should be chosen. The input contains the number of sessions in the first line.

Example
Input:

```
5
4 5
0 3
1 9
7 8
2 6
```

Output:

```
2
```

I tried this script:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

load = Counter()
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(n):
        session = f.readline()
        session = session.split()
        load.update(range(int(session[0]), int(session[1])+1))

load = load.most_common()
i = 0
max = load[0][1]
candidates = []
while load[i][1] == max:
    candidates.append(load[i][0])
    i += 1
print(min(candidates))
```

First, I use `Counter()` to count the occurrences of all points. Second, I use `load = load.most_common()` to order the resulting dict by occurrences. Finally I find the minimum value of all keys with the corresponding maximum value (= # of occurrences).

In fact, if `Counter()` returned a dict ordered by key, it would be much simpler.

Anyway, it is my home task and it runs more than 1 second (given time limit) on one of the test inputs. What could be done to speed it up? I've read about interval trees but I'm not sure if it is relevant.

Comment: "The most efficient" ... "with Python" is an eyebrow raiser. Why are you using Python if every nanosecond counts? How much readability do you want to trade for speed?

Comment: this looks awfully like a input for some http://www.hackerrank.com "riddle" ...

Comment: @timgeb I don't see any problem with that. suppose this condition is part of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `ins` and `outs` are the log in and log out times:

```
ins = [4,0,1,7,2]
outs = [5,3,9,8,6]
```

Combine them in one sorted list with the sign of the number indicating whether it is an "arrival" (positive) or "departure" (negative):

```
times = sorted(ins + [-x for x in outs], key=abs)
```

Now, walk through the list and count the "arrivals" and "departures" as they happen:

```
lmax = -1
logged = 0
for t in times:
    if t >= 0:
        logged += 1
        if logged > lmax:
            tmax = t
            lmax = logged
    else:
        logged -= 1

print(tmax, lmax)
#2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The fast solution for this is just storing +1, -1 on the enter/exit times - then sort the dict-keys and sum over it incrementally, followed by getting the maximal value:

```
data = """5
4 5
0 3
1 9
7 8
2 6"""
with open("input.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data) 

d = {}
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:  
        if line.strip():
            start, stop = map(int,line.strip().split())
            d.setdefault(start,0)
            d[start] += 1
            d.setdefault(stop,0)
            d[stop] -= 1

maxx = 0
s = 0
max_idx = 0

# iteratively summ over sorted times from dict
for idx,key in enumerate(sorted(d)):
    s += d[key]
    if maxx < s:  # remembert new max_idx and max
        maxx = s
        max_idx = idx
print(max_idx)
```

You can use a defaultdict(int) if that is still too slow to solve your challenge.